# form authentication with mvc framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, form-authentication

I am trying to do form Authentication with mvc framework,but if I login and copy the url  and logout from page and open in other browser or tab it should go to login page but its redirected to page which need to be first authenticate means goes directly inside login pages without  authentication 
.Any help will be aprreciated.

Here is my setting for web config:

```
 <!--Using forms authentication-->
        <location path="Content">
            <system.web>
                <authorization>
                    <allow users="*" />
                </authorization>
            </system.web>
        </location>

        <!-- allow any user to see the login controller -->
        <location path="~/Developer/Index">
            <system.web>
                <authorization>
                    <allow users="*" />
                </authorization>
            </system.web>
        </location>

               <authentication mode="Forms">
                <forms name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" loginUrl="~/Developer/Index" timeout="2880" />
            </authentication>

And in my controller login Action method i used 



     [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult LoginAPI(LoginAPIFormModel loginapp)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValidField("username") || !ModelState.IsValidField("pwd"))
            {
                if (!ModelState.IsValidField("username"))
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("username", "Invalid Email");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("Incomplete", "Please fill out each field");
                }


                return View(loginapp);
            }

            try
            {

                var context = new ndCorp_SiteEntities();
                var Hashpwd = CreateHash(loginapp.pwd);
                var res = context.DevUserInfoes.Where(i => i.UserName == loginapp.username && i.USerPwd == Hashpwd).FirstOrDefault() ;
 TempData["mode"] = "LoginAPI";

                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(loginapp.username, false);
                return RedirectToAction("SuccessView");
 }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Write(ex);
                return View(loginapp);
            }


        }
```

Here is the javascript code which actually redirect to user pag after login:

```
 if (@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(TempData["mode"])) == "LoginAPI")
       {
            parent.closeFancybox(); 
            //setTimeout(parent.closeFancybox(), 1000) 
            //window.top.closeFancybox();
             var url = '@Html.Raw(Url.Action("ManageApps", "Developer", new { username =@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(TempData["uname"]))} ))';
             url =  url.replace(/%22/g,'');
            parent.location.href = url;
        }
```

Comment: Try to be a bit more specific and maybe post a bit of the code. Also can you describe what you mean by "not working", any error codes or error messages?

Comment: I have again posted my query with more code...I am not getting any error but if I copy the url after login that url works in any browser or tab without authentication for eg. this url shouldn't work if I logogg from my application but its opening http://localhost:54971/en-us/Developer/ManageApps?username=test

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the [Authorize] attribute to your controller or view.